# In SSRS, how can I SUM by multiple groups?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sum

Please refer to the below table:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| | Company   | GL Account         | Amount              | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| | Company 1 | Cash at Bank ANZ   | $500,452.22         | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| |           | Westpac Investment | $443,233.32         | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| |           | NAB Cheque         | $9,833.22           | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| | Company 2 | Cash at Bank ANZ   | $938.22             | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| |           | Investment Online  | $940,404,400.20     | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| | Company 3 | Online Advantage   | $93,393.00          | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| |           | Direct Access      | $30.30              | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| |           | BAR Invest         | $192,330,303,300.10 | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| | TOTAL     |                    | $193,271,755,580.58 | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

This above table is what my SSRS report currently looks like.
As you can see, I have a group of companies. Each company has GL Accounts with multiple transactions however, I am only displaying the total for each GL account. For example, the top amount field "$500,452.22" is a total of ALL transactions for "Cash at Bank ANZ" for "Company 1". Furthermore, I have a total at the bottom, which is the total of ALL amount totals.

I want to add an additional total field which shows the total for ALL amounts fore each company. Basically, the report should look like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| | Company   | GL Account         | Amount              | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| | Company 1 | Cash at Bank ANZ   | $500,452.22         | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| |           | Westpac Investment | $443,233.32         | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| |           | NAB Cheque         | $9,833.22           | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| |           | TOTAL              | $953,518.76         | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| | Company 2 | Cash at Bank ANZ   | $938.22             | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| |           | Investment Online  | $940,404,400.20     | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| |           | TOTAL              | $940,405,338.42     | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| | Company 3 | Online Advantage   | $93,393.00          | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| |           | Direct Access      | $30.30              | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| |           | BAR Invest         | $192,330,303,300.10 | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| |           | TOTAL              | $192,330,396,723.40 | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
| | TOTAL     |                    | $193,271,755,580.58 | |
| +-----------+--------------------+---------------------+ |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Every time I try to create this total field, the report just displays duplicates of each GL Account total and not the total of all amounts per company.

Can anyone explain how to add the field that I want?

FYI: This is the SQL Query that I used:

```
select GLAC.GLCo as Company, HQCO.Name as 'Company Name', GLAC.Description as 'GL Description', GLDT.Amount as Amount from GLAC 

    LEFT JOIN HQCO ON
    GLAC.GLCo = HQCO.HQCo
    LEFT JOIN GLDT ON
    GLAC.GLCo = GLDT.GLCo and GLAC.GLAcct = GLDT.GLAcct
    where udCategory = 'Cash At Bank' and Active = 'Y'  and (GLAC.GLCo = 1 or GLAC.GLCo = 5 or GLAC.GLCo = 6 or GLAC.GLCo = 7)
```

Comment: In sQL, you would add `with rollup` or `grouping sets`.  Without seeing the query, it is hard to give the exact syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping in SSRS is certainly not intuitive.

I managed to achieve what I wanted by right clicking in the "Amount" field and then selecting "Insert Row" --> "Outside Group (Below)". I then put the sum in the new cell and everything was calculated how I desired.

Answer (score 1):

Managing groups went from really simple in SSRS 2005 to very difficult and arcane in SSRS 2008. Adding a footer to a group is the least intuitive UX ever.

To create a header or footer after the group has been created, go to the bottom of the design window where the `Row Groups` panel is. This will show your groups. Drop down the arrow on the `Detail` group (not the actual group you want to add the footer to but the group inside that) and you will see `Add Total` with a menu of `Before` or `After`. `Before` adds a header and `After` adds a footer to the group that encloses the item you are adding the total to.

Once the footer has been created put the expression `=SUM(Fields!Amount.Value)` into the column and it will sum the amount for your group.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly there is an option in SSRS 2008 R2 to add group sub-totals to a tablix when you add the group.

If you're trying to add them after the fact you can create a group footer row and then put your `=SUM(Field!Amount.Value)` in the Amount column and just hardcode the `TOTAL` text in the GL Account column. Since this is still being done inside the scope of the grouping it will only SUM() the values for that group.

Answer (score 0):

I think that , the 'Total' that you are looking will be equal to the sum of all Amount in the data set. I think this should work.

```
 1. Add a subtotal row   
 2. List item give its expression as SUM(Field!Amount.value)
```